# Difference between running command in PS shell and CMD shell

Tags: powershell

I don't use powershell often, so this may be an obvious question but my google-fu is failing me.

What is the difference between running the following commands, on a **Windows platform**?

In cmd prompt:
`C:\> powershell cd d:\foo`

and in powershell prompt:
`PS C:\> cd d:\foo`

The latter changes drive and directory as expected. The former does nothing.

Comment: You're changing the working directory of the powershell process, this does not change the working directory of the parent process. Both commands do the same, it's just that as the first piece of code returns back to CMD, which hasn't changed its working directory, you don't observe the actual change.

Comment: Try `powershell -c cd d:\foo;pwd` vs. `cd d:\foo;pwd` inside powershell, you'll see that in both instances it changed the working directory to d:\foo.

Comment: This should be an answer - very clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you run `powershell cd d:\foo` it opens a separate Powershell and runs the cd command. As opposed to the second one, you are actually in the Powershell session. So it, the first one, does open a Powershell process > change the directory and then it closes the process.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Don't know why I didn't think of that.